# Porque detectMultiScale no se detecta como atributo?

Tags: python

```
import cv2

x = cv2.CascadeClassifier("cars.xml")

innput = cv2.VideoCapture("video coche.mp4")#un video que he adjuntado para probar si funciona

while True:
    ret, leer_fotogramas = innput.read()
    gris = cv2.cvtColor(leer_fotogramas, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    coche = x.detectMultiScale(gris, 1.1, 4) #descripcion
    for (x, y, w, h) in coche:
        cv2.rectangle(leer_fotogramas, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2) #los ultimos cuatro 
numeros son 3primeros(color) y ultimo(grosor)
        #posibloe alarma sonora
    cv2.imshow('videoo', leer_fotogramas)

    codigo_ascii = cv2.waitKey(30)#para salir de programas (va a parte del resto)
    if codigo_ascii == 27:
        break

innput.release()
```

Reporta el problema:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\camara.py", line 11, in <module>
    coche = x.detectMultiScale(gris, 1.1, 4) #descripcion
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: Estás usando la misma variable `x` para dos cosas distintas. Después de que pasas por el `for` interno, `x` cambio de `cv2.CascadeClassifier` a ser una coordenada. Solución: usa un nombre más significativo para el primer `x`.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias ahora lo veo tiene bastante sentido, eso explica porque funcionaba un segundo y luego fallaba